# V-on mouseout fires when hovering on children

Tags: vuejs2

```
        <div style='cursor: pointer' v-for="row in rows" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light sidebar-item pl-2" :active="row.active">
            <div v-on:mouseout.stop="controls = null" v-on:mouseover="controls = row.id"  class="row">
                <div class="col-9">{{ row.title }}</div>
                <div v-if="controls == row.id" class="col-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                </div>
                <div v-if="controls == row.id" class="col-1">
                    <i class="text-danger fa fa-trash"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my code. `@mouseout` fires when the mouse hovers over the icons, even though they are still in the div and you haven't `mouseout`-ed practically.

I have tried with `@mouseover` and `@mouseout` on the parent div - same result. I have also tried all event modifiers I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviours of the eventlisteners `mouseover` or `mouseout`. If you want to ignore children you will have to either:

1. set the css property `pointer-events: none` on children, or
2. Check whether the cursor is inside the parent element in your event handler

However, for your use case (reveal an element when parent is hovered) css is more suitable.

E.g.

```
  .col-1 {
    display: none;
  }

  .row:focus > .col-1,
  .row:focus-within > col-1,
  .row:hover > col-1 {
    display: block;
  }
```